# Access sql query for most common product per customer

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been trawling the net to try and find an answer to this and keep stumbling!

I've got the following equivalent table:

City      |  Colour
Manchester |  Red
Manchester |  Red
Manchester |  Blue
Liverpool |  Red
Liverpool |   Red
Liverpool |   Orange
Liverpool |   Orange
Liverpool |   Orange

and I'm trying to get some sql together (for MS Access) that will output the most common colour for each city, i.e. the above would output to:

Manchester |  Red
Liverpool  |  Orange

can anyone help!?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City, Colour
FROM t
WHERE Colour = (SELECT TOP 1 Colour
                FROM t As t2
                WHERE City = t.City
                GROUP BY Colour
                ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, Colour
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain in MS Access, but you can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select city, colour
from t as t
group by city, colour
having count(*) = (select top 1 count(*)
                   from t as t2
                   where t2.city = t.city
                   group by t2.colour
                   order by count(*) desc, t2.colour
                  );
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, I'm getting a syntax error unfortunately  in the having section.  See what you mean about it being a pain!

Comment: Access seems not to like the brackets in `top (1)`. It should work with just `top 1`.

Comment: @WolfgangKais . . . This is a mistake I make all the time, because the parentheses are accepted (and in fact seem needed) based on the syntax diagrams for SQL Server.